# C# CF2.0 Delegate CreateDelegate Workaround

Tags: c#, reflection, compact-framework, compact-framework2.0

As you may no there is now Delegate.CreateDelegate Method in Compact Framework 2.0. So i'm searching for a Workaround to get this functionality work at CF2.0.

```
Delegate.CreateDelegate()
```

I found some Links that should help me, but i didn't got it at the moment.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8162/Using-MyXaml-on-the-Compact-Framework
http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/824155-delegate-createdelegate-equivalent-netcf

My specific Problem is that i need a generic Delegate because i get my Types from a dynamic loaded Assembly using Reflection.

*EventArgs: Symbol.ResourceCoordination.TriggerEventArgs*

*EventHandler: Symbol.ResourceCoordination.Trigger.TriggerEventHandler*

*Event: Symbol.ResourceCoordination.Trigger.TriggerEventHandler Stage2Notify*

```
Type triggerEventArgsType = asm.GetType("Symbol.ResourceCoordination.TriggerEventArgs, Symbol.ResourceCoordination, 2.5.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=68EC8DB391F150CA");
Type triggerType = asm.GetType("Symbol.ResourceCoordination.Trigger, Symbol.ResourceCoordination, 2.5.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=68EC8DB391F150CA");

EventInfo eventInfo = triggerType.GetEvent("Stage2Notify");
Type eventHandlerType = eventInfo.EventHandlerType;

eventInfo.AddEventHandler(???)
```